# Relatively large index scan although PK condition exists in where clause, caused by order by stmt

Tags: postgresql

I have a query optimization problem where index scan happens, when there is a condition limiting the number of records being scanned:

```
Explain analyze
select id
FROM            "item"
WHERE           "item"."project_id" = 'c257e25f-1db7-410d-a6fb-73de793a5c8d'
ORDER BY        "item"."identifier" DESC limit 50;

Index Scan Backward using item_identifier on submittals_item  (cost=0.42..46809.93 rows=2164 width=20)
```

Number of item records for this project_id is

```
select count(*) from item where project_id='c257e25f-1db7-410d-a6fb-73de793a5c8d';
 count
-------
  2259
(1 row)
```

I like to prevent the order by stmt scanning 46k records, when there are only 2259 items in this project.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks for the heads up, I mistakenly called it container_id, it's the project_id. Changed the question

Comment: How long since the table was analyzed?  And the DDL, please.

Comment: You should consider adding an index on `(project_id, identifier)` or replacing the `(project_id)` index with it. Please add the output of `\d item`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ. yep, it worked! Thanks

Comment: For future performance questions: only showing the part of the execution plan that you think is relevant is typically not helpful. Always show the complete plan (ideally generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: The cost is not a count of the number of rows to be scanned.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an index on (project_id, identifier) resolved it.

Now it's

```
Index Scan Backward using item_identifier_project on item (cost=0.42..7432.78 rows=2087 width=20) (actual time=0.037..0.106 rows=50 loops=1)
```